# How to use `timezone` from OpenWeatherMap API response to get the local time of a city in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, openweathermap

I have a web page that displays the weather of a city based on the user input. Every time the user enters a city name in an input box, I want to **display the current time in that city in its respective timezone**. The OpenWeatherMap API response has a `timezone` attribute but I don't know how to use it.

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="date-time">
    <h1 class="time">
      00:00:00
    </h1>
    <h2 class="date">

    </h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
setInterval(() => {
  // 12Hr Format For Hour
  function twilveFormat(hour) {
    if (hour >= 13) {
      return hour % 12;
    } else {
      return hour;
    }
  }

  function isAM_PM(hour) {
    if (hour >= 12) {
      return "AM";
    } else {
      return "PM";
    }
  }

  const days = [
    "Sunday",
    "Monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "Thursay",
    "Friday",
    "Saturday"
  ];
  const months = [
    "Jan",
    "Feb",
    "March",
    "Apr",
    "May",
    "Jun",
    "July",
    "Aug",
    "Sep",
    "Oct",
    "Nov",
    "Dec"
  ];

  const time = new Date();

  const date = time.getDate();
  const month = time.getMonth();
  const day = time.getDay();
  const min = time.getMinutes();
  const sec = time.getSeconds();
  const hour = time.getHours();
  const hourIn12HR = twilveFormat(hour);
  const isAM = isAM_PM(hour);

  // Time
  document.querySelector(
    ".content .date-time .time"
  ).innerHTML = `${hourIn12HR}:${min}:${sec} <span id='AM_PM'>${isAM}</span>`;

  // Date

  document.querySelector(
    ".content .date-time .date"
  ).innerHTML = `${days[day]}, ${date} ${months[month]}`;
}, 1000);
```

I use Openweathermap API:

```
const res = await fetch(
  `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&units=metric&appid=${this.apiKey}`
);
const data = await res.json();
this.display(data);
```

HTML input:

```
<div action="" class="myform">
  <input type="" class="search" placeholder="Search">
  <button class="myBtn"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The response of the [current weather API call](https://openweathermap.org/current#name) has 2 fields which can be used to get the local time of a city at the time when the API call was made:

> `dt` : Time of data calculation, unix, UTC

> `timezone` : Shift in seconds from UTC

```js
  function getDate(dt, timezone) {
    const utc_seconds = parseInt(dt, 10) + parseInt(timezone, 10);
    const utc_milliseconds = utc_seconds * 1000;
    const local_date = new Date(utc_milliseconds).toUTCString();
    return local_date;
  }
```

After awaiting the API response, use the function as follows :

```js
 const API_response = {
   "coord": {
     "lon": -99.1277,
     "lat": 19.4285
   },
   "weather": [{
       "id": 721,
       "main": "Haze",
       "description": "haze",
       "icon": "50d"
     },
     {
       "id": 701,
       "main": "Mist",
       "description": "mist",
       "icon": "50d"
     }
   ],
   "base": "stations",
   "main": {
     "temp": 287.11,
     "feels_like": 286.7,
     "temp_min": 282.4,
     "temp_max": 287.11,
     "pressure": 1026,
     "humidity": 82
   },
   "visibility": 8047,
   "wind": {
     "speed": 0,
     "deg": 0
   },
   "clouds": {
     "all": 0
   },
   "dt": 1667656987,
   "sys": {
     "type": 1,
     "id": 7146,
     "country": "MX",
     "sunrise": 1667651955,
     "sunset": 1667692857
   },
   "timezone": -21600,
   "id": 3530597,
   "name": "Mexico City",
   "cod": 200
 }
 
 console.log(getDate(API_response.dt, API_response.timezone)) // "Sat, 05 Nov 2022 08:03:07 GMT"
// When I called the API, the actual time in Mexico City was 08:03:07.
```

#### How it works

Taking above `API_response` as an example,

- First convert `dt` and `timezone` to integers.
- `dt` represents the number of seconds since January 1st, 1970 UTC and `timezone` indicates by how many seconds the timezone in Mexico City is different from UTC.
- Adding these two integers gives the number of seconds **from January 1st, 1970 to current time in Mexico City**. To convert this into a date, we must use `new Date(...)`.
- In JS, `new Date()` accepts only utc in milliseconds so we must convert `utc_seconds` to milliseconds.
- `new Date(utc_milliseconds)` gives the current time in Mexico City **in my local timezone** which is different from the timezone in Mexico City.
- `new Date(utc_milliseconds).toUTCString()` changes the timezone accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your goal you first need to get the timezone-property and parse it to your need. By looking at the OpenWeatherMap API I can see that the response contains a "timezone"-property which gives you the shift in seconds from UTC time for that city.
So what you can try: You can fetch the current time at your location using

```
var x = new Date();
```

Next you add the amount of seconds that the timezone-property holds. (of course you need to parse it to a number first)
like so:

```
x.setSeconds(x.getSeconds + {timezoneParsed});
```

That will return you the city's current time as number of ticks.
Next you just out put the current time in human readable format like so for instance:

```
x.toISOString();
```

Comment: Hello sir, I tried your way. It didn't work this is the error that is occurred;  Uncaught RangeError: invalid date

I just need to make sure that I understand you well. 
Firstly, do you mean by timezoneParsed is the same API proberty of time zone? It's in this case 10800; this is the URL http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=basra&units=metric&appid=0067d86bf6bb4db36fc3b5cda752cca0

secondly, what do you mean by parsing it, into int or what?
Thirdly, after I make it should I get the hour, min, and sec from the same x ?

Comment: By implementing just this; console.log(time.setSeconds(time.getSeconds + 10800));
I get an error of NaN